# How to underline hotkeys on Google Chrome or Chromium right-click menu?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, chromium, accessibility

The hotkeys on the Google Chrome right-click menu are not underlined.

For example, from the right-click menu, we can press <kbd>T</kbd> to open a link in a new tab and we can press <kbd>V</kbd> to "save image as"

On Windows, there is an option to "underline access keys when available" in the accessibility options that will underline the corresponding letters for these keys on the Google Chrome right-click menu.

It would be nice to know these keys so we could use them and Google does not have them listed anywhere that I can find.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I _do_ get the underline decoration **if I Alt-Tab to another window and then once more back to Chromium before opening the contextual menu**. Weird. Dunno if they’re aware of this issue. Doesn’t look like it’ll be fixed anytime soon and it’s my main grievance with Chromium currently, haha.

Answer (score 4):

In case we don't have the ability to underline the keys, I went ahead and compiled a list of hotkeys for the Google Chrome right-click menu:

Link context menu:

```
open-link-in-new-tab    -       t
open-link-in-new-window -       w
open-link-in-incognito  -       g
save-link-as            -       k
copy-link-address       -       e
inspect                 -       n
```

Image context menu:

```
open-image-in-new-tab   -       i
save-image-as           -       v
copy-image              -       y
copy-image-address      -       o
google-image-search     -       s
```

Page context menu:

```
save-as                 -       a
back                    -       b
forward                 -       f
reload                  -       r
cast                    -       c
translate               -       t
print                   -       p
view-page-source        -       v
```

Selected/Highlighted text context menu:

```
copy                    -       c
search-text             -       s
print-text              -       p
```

We can use this list as a workaround for reference but I'm still open for any answers.